# Wrapping sudo & ssh command inside bash

Tags: bash

I need to switch to sudo user and then run a command on remote server using SSH

Actual command

```
docker stats --no-stream --format  "\"{{ .Name }}\^C{\"memory\":{\"raw\":\"{{ .MemUsage }}\",\"percent\":\"{{ .MemPerc }}\"},\"Node\":\"{{ \"`hostname -i`\" }}\",\"cpu\":\"{{ .CPUPerc }}\"},"
```

running from ssh also works

```
ssh 1.2.3.4 'docker stats --no-stream --format  "\"{{ .Name }}\^C{\"memory\":{\"raw\":\"{{ .MemUsage }}\",\"percent\":\"{{ .MemPerc }}\"},\"Node\":\"{{ \"`hostname -i`\" }}\",\"cpu\":\"{{ .CPUPerc }}\"},"'
```

But when i try to pass it as `sudo su - core -c` its not working because " pattern matching. How to properly wrap this command ?

```
sudo su - core -c 'ssh 1.2.3.4 'docker stats --no-stream --format  "\"{{ .Name }}\^C{\"memory\":{\"raw\":\"{{ .MemUsage }}\",\"percent\":\"{{ .MemPerc }}\"},\"Node\":\"{{ \"`hostname -i`\" }}\",\"cpu\":\"{{ .CPUPerc }}\"},"''
```

Comment: i tried `command='docker stats --no-stream --format  "\"{{ .Name }}\^C{\"memory\":{\"raw\":\"{{ .MemUsage }}\",\"percent\":\"{{ .MemPerc }}\"},\"Node\":\"{{ \"`hostname -i`\" }}\",\"cpu\":\"{{ .CPUPerc }}\"}," ';sudo su - core -c 'ssh 1.2.3.4 $command'` that didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler with here-document :

```
sudo su - core << 'END_SUDO'
  ssh self << 'END_SSH'
docker stats --no-stream --format  '"{{ .Name }}{"memory":{"raw":"{{ .MemUsage }}","percent":"{{ .MemPerc }}"},"Node":"{{ "'"$(hostname -i)"'" }}","cpu":"{{ .CPUPerc }}"},'
END_SSH
END_SUDO
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But one problem when I am using `ssh -q` it still prints banner. Any idea how to supress ssh banner here ?

Comment: `-q` is supposed to suppress most warning and diagnostic messages, not the banner.

If you have control on ssh server, you can set `PrintMotd=no`